# How do I export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe with regedit from cmd.exe?

Tags: command-line, regedit, escape-characters

I am trying to export the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_system32_cmd.exe` but am unable to do so, probably because of the percent signs.

I tried to escape the %-sign with a caret or another %-sign, but this didn't help me:

```
regedit /e c:\temp\cmd.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe"
```

and

```
regedit /e c:\temp\cmd.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\^%SystemRoot^%_system32_cmd.exe"
```

So, is there a way to do what I want.

**Edit** as per *Ярослав Рахматуллин's* comment: the key *is* the exact string, with the percent signs. So I don't want `%SystemRoot%` expanded, but passed to regedit *as is*.

Comment: Do you want the variable to expand? As in do you want the key located at what would be the location in the tree if the proper value for the system root was inserted instead of variable?

Comment: No, the variable should not be expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [Using a percent sign (%) in a batch file requires that two percent signs (%%) be specified.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120806070159/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634)

This is working **in batch files**.

```
regedit /e c:\temp\123.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%SystemRoot%%_system32_cmd.exe"
```

2. This trick is working in "plain" command line of cmd.exe

```
set sr=SystemRoot
regedit /e c:\temp\123.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%%sr%%_system32_cmd.exe"
```

Comment: It would be great to explain *why* this is working. A little context always helps!

Comment: Sorry, it's more easy :)

Comment: It's interesting that this works in batch files. But I was actually after a way to run (or type) this in cmd.exe itself. And it doesn't work if not in a batch file.

Comment: Trick for command line

Comment: Do yourself a favor and install the PowerShell. CMD.exe is really not suitable, ...for anything.